# PhantomJs Emulate IE8

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm triying to get some data scraping a websystem (created on ASP) wich only run correctly on IE8 , i set user-agent as **Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)**, but it doesn't works, i'm still getting this reference error
 **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cmbBolsa**, cmbBolsa it's a comboBox

Here's my code

```
var page1 = require('webpage').create(),
pag1 = 'URL',
dat1 = 'usuario=user&contrasenia=pass';


page1.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT      5.1; Trident/4.0)';
page1.open(pag1, 'post', dat1);
page1.onLoadFinished = function(){

page1.evaluate(function(){ 
        document.getElementById('frmPantalla').src='http://myurl/planif.do?action=resumPlan';
 document.getElementById('mensaje').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('fondo').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementsByName('anioProgramaSelected').selectedIndex="2015";

 var element = document.querySelector( 'img#img_gral_ejecutar' );  
 var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
 event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0 );                   
 element.dispatchEvent( event );  });


    window.setTimeout(function () {
      page1.render('./prueba.png');
      phantom.exit();
}, 60000);};
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript library to simulate Internet Explorer JavaScript environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410860/javascript-library-to-simulate-internet-explorer-javascript-environment)

Comment: See also [my thoughts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26752000/1816580) why you can't do this in PhantomJS.